# Obtener el valor de un radiobutton

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Tengo el siguiente problema
quiero actualizar el estado de un usuario mediante un `radiobutton`  y
quiero obtener el valor del `radiobutton` seleccionado para hacer un `update` en la base de datos.

El problema esta es cuando selección del radio no me manda ningún valor.

Muestro código para que miren como lo hago.

Este el código `JS` donde llamo al valor y dependiendo del radio seleccionado que la variable esta "Estado" agarre el valor del radio seleccionado

```js
<!--llamada a la funcion actualiza  usuarios-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#actualizadatos').click(function(){
    ID=$('#ID_Usuario').val();
 Nombres=$('#Nombres').val();
 Apellidos=$('#Apellidos').val();
 Identidad=$('#Identidad').val();
 Correo=$('#Correo').val();
 Usuario=$('#Usuario').val();
 Password=$('#Password').val();
    Nivel_Permiso=$('#Nivel_Permiso').val();

    var radio1 = document.getElementById("Activo");
    var radio2 = document.getElementById("Inactivo");
  
    if($("#radio1").is(':checked')) {
      Estado=$('input[name=Activo]:checked', '#ModalEdicion').val();
    }else if($("#radio2").is(':checked')) {
      Estado=$('input[name=Inactivo]:checked', '#ModalEdicion').val();
   }
 
   alert(Estado);
 actualizadatos(ID,Nombres,Apellidos,Identidad,Correo,Usuario,Password,Nivel_Permiso,Estado)
  
  });
  
});
</script>
```

```html
Este es del html, estoy usando una modal para el formulario.

<label>Estado del Usuario: </label>
      <input type="radio" name="Activo" id="Activo" value="Activo"> Activo
      <input type="radio" name="Inactivo" id="Inactivo" value="Inactivo"> Inactivo
```

Gracias por sus respuestas. :))

Comment: Donde estas enviados los datos? a un archivo php? y la función actualizadatos() donde esta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que puedas trabajar con radio y checkbox debes usar su naturaleza ante el DOM con el atributo `name` (Aunque también puedes hacerlo por `class`)

```js
//Cuando el DOM esté listo
$( () => {
  
  //Creamos el listener del boton
  $(document).on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function(){
      
      //Traemos los radio que tengan el mismo name, únicamente los que estén seleccionados y sacamos el valor
      let radio = $('input[name="isActive"]:checked').val();
      
      if( radio ) {
        console.log( radio );
      }
    
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="isActive" value="Activo"> Activo
<input type="radio" name="isActive" value="Inactivo"> Inactivo
<input type="button" value="Probar">
```

Tu Js quedaría así con un poco de performace y buen gusto

```
//Lo mismo que el document.ready
$( () => {

    //Es mejor pedirle al DOM que haga la búsqueda del selector, a veces no funciona como tu lo tienes
    $( document ).on('click', '#actualizadatos', function() {

        //Declara tus variables, utiliza los estándares de ES6 o ES5
        let id            = $('#ID_Usuario').val(),
            nombres       = $('#Nombres').val(),
            apellidos     = $('#Apellidos').val(),
            identidad     = $('#Identidad').val(),
            correo        = $('#Correo').val(),
            usuario       = $('#Usuario').val(),
            password      = $('#Password').val(),
            nivel_permiso = $('#Nivel_Permiso').val(),
            estado        = $('input[name="isActive"]:checked').val() || '';
            //El estado si es undefined entonces toma un valor vacío

        //Invoca tu función
        actualizadatos( id, nombres, apellidos, identidad, correo,
                        usuario, password, nivel_permiso, estado);
    });

});
```

También cambia algo en tu HTML intenta dejar un radio checkeado por default, para que no te lies más con el código y se vea más limpia la recolección de datos.

```
<input type="radio" name="isActive" id="Activo" value="Activo" checked> Activo
<input type="radio" name="isActive" id="Inactivo" value="Inactivo"> Inactivo
```

Comment: gracias me sirvio :))

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener el valor de tu radio button basta hacer lo siguiente con jQuery:

```
$("input[name='el_nombre_de_tu_radio']:checked").val();
```

Esta condición: `if($("#radio1").is(':checked'))` no te funcionará ya que estás haciendo la selección mediante `id` y sospecho que tus inputs radio les asignaste un mismo `id`, debería de ser como lo siguiente:

```
if($("input[name='el_nombre_de_tu_radio']").is(':checked')){
   //Más código aquí
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Saludos puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
$('input:radio[name="estado"]').change(
    function(){
        if (this.checked && this.value == '1') {
        alert('Activo');
        }else{
         alert('Inactivo');
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="estado">Estado Usuario</label>
<br>
<label for="estado">
<input type="radio" name="estado" id="estado" value="1">Activo
</label><br>
<label for="estado">
<input type="radio" name="estado" id="estado" value="0">Inactivo
</label>
```

Podemos notar que mediante el name detecto algun cambio y dentro de este valido que me retorna dado que en los radio button determine un valor para cada estado.

Existen muchas formas de hacerlo por ID, por NAME, por CLASS etc..

Answer (score 0):

```js
aqui es donde mando los valores 


//funcion para actualizar datos
function actualizadatos(ID,Nombres,Apellidos,Identidad,Correo,Usuario,Nivel_Permiso,Estado) {
    
    
    cadena="&ID=" + ID + 
           "&Nombres=" + Nombres + 
           "&Apellidos=" + Apellidos +  
            "&Identidad=" + Identidad +
            "&Correo=" + Correo +
            "&Usuario=" + Usuario +
            "&Nivel_Permiso=" + Nivel_Permiso +
            "&Estado=" + Estado ;

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"actualizaDatos.php",
                data:cadena,
                success:function (r) {
                    if (r==1) {
                        //mensaje de correcto
                        alertify.success("Usuario Actualizado Correctamente"); 
                        //al momento que se agregue un dato se vuela a recargar la tabla
                        location.reload(true);
                    }else{
                        //mensaje de error
                       alertify.success("Fallo en el servidor");
                        
                    }
                }
           
               });
               
               
}
```

```html
Este es el update de la base datos

<?php

 //conexion a la base de datos
 include 'conexion.php';


 //almacena los datos ingresados en los textboxs
 $ID=$_POST['ID'];
 $nomb=$_POST['Nombres']; 
 $apell=$_POST['Apellidos'];
 $ident=$_POST['Identidad'];
 $email=$_POST['Correo']; 
 $user=$_POST['Usuario']; 
 $perm=$_POST['Nivel_Permiso'];
 $estado=$_POST['Estado']
//sentencia update para actualizar datos
 $sql="UPDATE usuario set Nombres='$nomb', 
                          Apellidos='$apell', 
                          Identidad='$ident', 
                          correo='$email', 
                          Usuario='$user', 
                          Nivel_Permiso='$perm',
                          Estado='$estado'
                          where ID_Usuario='$ID'";

                        
//condicional para saber si el insert se ejecuto correctamente
if (mysqli_query($conexion,$sql)==TRUE) {
    echo 1;
} 

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Te recomiendo que al utilizar tipo radio para validar que solo sea una opción la que pueda elegir le pongas el atributo `name` con el mismo valor, así lo puedes seleccionar, recuerda que al seleccionarlo de esta manera te trae un array, así que lo debes de recorrer y con `this.value` obtienes el valor del input seleccionado, te dejo un ejemplo, espero te sirva, comente tu código sólo para que observaras el ejemplo y lo modificaras a tu gusto.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#actualizadatos').click(function(){
    ID=$('#ID_Usuario').val();
  Nombres=$('#Nombres').val();
  Apellidos=$('#Apellidos').val();
  Identidad=$('#Identidad').val();
  Correo=$('#Correo').val();
  Usuario=$('#Usuario').val();
  Password=$('#Password').val();
    Nivel_Permiso=$('#Nivel_Permiso').val();
    
    $("input[name=estado]").each(function(){
                    if(this.checked)
                    {
                        if(this.value == 'Activo'){
                          
                          console.log('Haz algo cuando esta activo');
                        
                        }else{
                        
                        console.log('Haz algo cuando esta inactivo');
                        
                        }
                    }
                });
      
    
    
    /*var radio1 = document.getElementById("Activo");
    var radio2 = document.getElementById("Inactivo");*/
  
    /*if($("#Activo").is(':checked')) {
      Estado=$('input[name=Activo]:checked', '#ModalEdicion').val();
    }else if($("#Inactivo").is(':checked')) {
      Estado=$('input[name=Inactivo]:checked', '#ModalEdicion').val();
   }*/
   
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Estado del Usuario: </label>
      <input type="radio" name="estado" id="Activo" value="Activo"> Activo
      <input type="radio" name="estado" id="Inactivo" value="Inactivo"> Inactivo
      
     <button id="actualizadatos">Actualiza</button>
```

Comment: ALguien que haya puesto el -1, me podría explicar la razón? :)